# How to make jQuery ui tab be as wide as the objects inside of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, html-table, width, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a table inside of one of the tabs and it's longer than the width of the default jQuery ui tabs width so it looks ugly.

Is there a way to change the width of the tab to be as wide as the table inside of it?

Comment: can you show jsfiddle.net demo of your problem

Comment: I'm working on IE8 and jsfiddle doesn't work with IE8 :/ but it's just creating a table inside of one of the tabs and add a super long textfield

Comment: @rahulmaindargi you'll see that the width of the border is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be using the table width in pixels i guess. As the code is not provided i can do some guess work only. Try changing the table width to percentage and try.

> Please post the code, so the question will be clearer...

This is just an assumption. Please look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqHzj/4/) 
I have worked out a solution that may help you.

**HTML**

```
<div id="tabs" width="1000px">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Actual Tab</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Problem</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">problem fix</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    Flexible tab
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
        <td>Column 1 Content</td>
        <td>Column 2 Content</td>
        <td>Column 3 Content</td>
        <td>Column 4 Content</td>
        <td>Column 5 Content</td>
        <td>Column 6 Content</td>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
    this is a table with Fixed width so this will go beyond your tab
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" width ="900px">
        <td>Column 1 Content</td>
        <td>Column 2 Content</td>
        <td>Column 3 Content</td>
        <td>Column 4 Content</td>
        <td>Column 5 Content</td>
        <td>Column 6 Content</td>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" width ="100%">
        <td>Column 1 Content</td>
        <td>Column 2 Content</td>
        <td>Column 3 Content</td>
        <td>Column 4 Content</td>
        <td>Column 5 Content</td>
        <td>Column 6 Content</td>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
```

***EDIT :***

**CSS**

```
div#tabs{
  width: 1000px;
}
```

The Css will do the trick just add it and try
Hope this helps

Comment: this is a nice approach! thanks! but it does not solve my problem. each td has a textfield with a size 12, so even if I change the width of the table, it has a default size for what's inside the tab, I guess changing the width of the whole table with the tabs would work but that's what I don't know how to do

Comment: so you have text field with size 12px. How many columns are there in your tab?

Comment: randomizertech : Look please have a look at the edited answer.

Comment: the CSS did the trick! I don't know how I didn't think of this before! Thank you!!